# SQL: Apply sequence number to a column based on nth occurrence of each distinct value

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column of values where each value occurs a variable number of times (i.e., one value may occur 1 time, and another value may occur 3 times).  I need to add a column that identifies the occurrence sequence # of its corresponding value.

Input Table

| SOURCE_VAL |
| --- |
| a |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| c |
| c |

Output table

| SEQUENCE_VAL | SOURCE_VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | c |

What would the SQL for this be to generate the SEQUENCE_VAL column based on SOURCE_VAL?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `row_number()`.  Without an ordering column, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by source_val order by source_val) as sequence_val
from t
order by source_val, sequence_val;
```

Note:  This assumes that you do not care about the ordering of the value.  If you have another column that does specify the ordering for each `source_val`, then use that in the `order by`.